# MySQL using BETWEEN not returning anything?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, between

I am trying to get all rows from my MySQL database that are from the last week and also have the right `company_id`.  I don't understand why this isn't returning any data, as there are no errors.

A screenshot of the database:
[image]

My code:

```java
// Create Calendar and Date objects
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

// Get all datapoints from last week from this company's id
query = "SELECT * FROM survey_data WHERE (company_id = ?) AND (date_entered BETWEEN ? + interval ? day AND ? + interval ? day)";
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, companyId);
preparedStatement.setDate(2, date);
preparedStatement.setInt(3, -Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK - 6);
preparedStatement.setDate(4, date);
preparedStatement.setInt(5, -Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Have you traced your code to see what the query looks like going over the wire?

Comment: what is interval and day in middle of query?

Comment: @RossBush  To be honest, I don't even know what "the wire" is.  Could you explain?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani This is MySQL's version of `DATEADD()`, which adds X days to the date. (In my case, X is negative, so it subracts days from the date)

Comment: @JaydeepGalani - I mean can you inspect the variable query either before it is sent on the backend. Can you take the value of query and run it against MySQL to see if it is valid SQL?

Comment: @RossBush So, I tested it in MySQL workbench and realized that I needed tick marks around my date as such: `'2019-02-12'`  However, the issue is that when I use PreparedStatement, putting those ticks around the `?` makes it so that it is no longer considered a parameter and it now thinks I only have 3 parameters without the two date parameters.